# SpringBoot liveness and readiness endpoints not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We are deploying spring boot app on openshift having liveness and readiness probes enabled.

In application properties have below properties

spring.main.web-application-type=servlet
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true

management.health.livenessstate.enabled=true

management.health.readineasstate.enabled=true

For this properties able to get details for /actuator/health endpoints including livenessstate and readiness state with other information.

But getting 500 error for /actuator/health/liveness and /actuator/health/redladiness endpoints.

Which properties I am missing.

Spring Boot version - 2.3.2.RELEASE